# Eliminar datos de multiples tablas con un patron. PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Quiero eliminar los datos de todas las tablas que se llaman empleados* donde el nombre sea daniel. 
Todas las tablas tienen la misma estructura.

Ejemplo de nombres de las tablas.
empleados1
empleados2
empleados_1
empleados_21

Estructura de todas las tablas.
id,nombre,sexo

Delete from empleados*
where nombre = 'daniel'

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar?

Comment: Es que tengo una serie de tablas con nombre generico (un patron) como explico y lo que necesito es eliminar de TODAS esas tablas un  valor determinado. Las tablas se van creando de forma dinamica asi que no siempre es la misma cantidad y necesito una consulta, si se p[uede, para eliminarlas de todas esas tablas. La idea seria un: Delete from empleados* where nombre = 'daniel'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes crear una funcion en plpgsql que haga lo que requires, algo como esto:

```
create or replace function elimina_tabla_patron (esquema text,tabla_patron text, valor_a_eliminar text) returns void as 
$$
declare
tab text;
comando  text;
begin

for tab in select schemaname||'.'||tablename from pg_tables where schemaname=esquema and tablename like tabla_patron loop
 raise notice ' tabla: %' ,tab;
 comando:= 'DELETE from '|| tab || ' WHERE nombre='''||valor_a_eliminar ||'''';
 raise notice ' Ejecutando: %' ,comando;
 execute comando;

end loop;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

para llamarla puedes hacer(los parametros son: esquema, patron de tabla y el valor por el cual vas a borrar):

```
select * from elimina_tabla_patron('public','empleados%','daniel')
```

recuerda pasar el patron de las tablas con el comodin %, asegurate que sean el patron correcto, pues puedes borrar datos no deseados.

saludos

Comment: El problema es que tengo mas tablas dentro del esquema y me las lista todas, no solamente las del patron.

Comment: Error mio, estaba poniendo mal el patron. Estoy ahora mismo testiando.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciona perfecto!!!!!